# How to Compare two columns data of two table and save its difference in percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

Table1

```
ID   SID    Date        value
1    1  2017-12-31  22.36
1    1  2018-03-31  20.0
1    1  2018-06-30  10.87
1    1  2018-09-30  67.98
1    2  2017-12-31  55.987
1    2  2018-03-31  60.12
1    2  2018-06-30  62.0
1    2  2018-09-30  15.543
1    3  2017-12-31  85.987
1    3  2018-03-31  40.12
1    3  2018-06-30  12.0
1    3  2018-09-30  15.543
```

Table2

```
ID  SID     Date        value
2    1  2017-12-31     22.36
2    1  2018-03-31     10.0
2    1  2018-06-30     10.87
2    1  2018-09-30     67.98
2    2  2017-12-31     55.987
2    2  2018-03-31     60.12
2    2  2018-06-30     31.0
2    2  2018-09-30     15.543
2    3  2017-12-31     85.987
2    3  2018-03-31     40.12
2    3  2018-06-30     06.0
```

Table1 is the base table.

Table1 and Table2 contain quarterly data,SID is common in these two tables.

I am trying to achieve :

- To find out the percentage of decrease/increase in values column of
  respective SID's of Table1 and Table 2.if SID of Table1 and Table2 is
  missing then a show a message.

below is the expected result

```
ID   SID    Date        value     percent increase/decrease
1    1    2017-12-31    22.36     0
1    1   2018-03-31    20.018     50
1    1   2018-06-30    10.87      0
1    1   2018-09-30    67.98      0
1    2   2017-12-31    55.987     0
1    2   2018-03-31    60.12      0
1    2   2018-06-30    31.0       50
1    2   2018-09-30    15.543     0
1    3   2017-12-31    85.987     0
1    3   2018-03-31    40.12      0
1    3   2018-06-30    12.0       50
1    3    2018-09-30  15.543     data not available to compare in table 2
```

is this achievable ? 
I am trying to write a query to achieve this by JOIN however nowhere near to it. below is the sample query.

```
 SELECT t1.ID,t1.SID,t1.Date,t1.value,
 CASE WHEN (t1.Value -t2.Value/t1.value)*100=50 THEN '50'  END AS 'percent increase/decrease'
 FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 
 ON t1.SID=t2.SID
```

any hints/idea on this?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW - if this is a single database - you might want to reconsider database design, both tables have the same structure, so they could be one table with an identifier field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you also need to join on the date. And use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER`

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    t1.SID,
    t1.Date,
    t1.value,
    CASE 
        WHEN (t1.Value -t2.Value/t1.value)*100=50 THEN '50' 
        WHEN t2.Value is null then 'data not available to compare in table 2'
        ELSE '0' 
    END AS 'percent increase/decrease'
 FROM table t1 LEFT JOIN table t2 
 ON t1.SID=t2.SID 
 and t1.Date = t2.Date
```

Comment: No problem @TechnoSavvy

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*,
       case when t2.[Value] is null then null else (t1.[value] - t2.[value])/t1.[value] end
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.SID = t2.SID and t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
```

It will give `null` when there's no corresponding value in `Table2`. I think is better than mixing numbers and text (two datatypes) in one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
        case when t1.id is null or t2.id is null then cast(coalesce(t1.id,t2.id) as varchar(20)) + ' missing' else 'ok' end status,
        t1.id,
        t1.sid,
        t1.date, 
        t1.value, 
        100.000 * (t1.value - t2.value)/t2.value as percchange 
                from Table1 t1 full join 
                    table2 t2 
                        on T1.id = t2.id and t1.sid=t2.sid and t1.DATE = t2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I am expanding on scsimon's query. I added the brackets on the fuction and cast to varchar so as to have the same datatype for the nulls.

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE (ID int, SID int, ADate date, value real)
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT 1,     1,  '2017-12-31',  22.36 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     1,  '2018-03-31',   20.0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     1,  '2018-06-30',   10.87 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     1,  '2018-09-30',   67.98 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     2,  '2017-12-31',   55.987 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     2,  '2018-03-31',   60.12 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     2,  '2018-06-30',   62.0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     2,  '2018-09-30',  15.543 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     3,  '2017-12-31',   85.987 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     3,  '2018-03-31',   40.12 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     3,  '2018-06-30',   12.0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,     3,  '2018-09-30',   15.543

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE (ID int, SID int, ADate date, value real)
INSERT INTO @TABLE2
SELECT 2,    1,  '2017-12-31',     22.36 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    1,  '2018-03-31',     10.0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    1,  '2018-06-30',     10.87 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    1,  '2018-09-30',     67.98 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    2,  '2017-12-31',     55.987 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    2,  '2018-03-31',     60.12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    2,  '2018-06-30',     31.0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    2,  '2018-09-30',     15.543 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    3,  '2017-12-31',     85.987 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    3,  '2018-03-31',     40.12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    3,  '2018-06-30',     06.0




SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    t1.SID,
    t1.ADate,
    t1.value,
    [percent increase/decrease]=CASE        
        WHEN t2.Value is null THEN 'data not available to compare in table 2'
        ELSE CAST(((t1.Value - t2.Value)/t1.value)*100 AS varchar(20))
    END
 FROM @TABLE1 t1 

 LEFT JOIN @TABLE2 t2  ON 
    t1.SID=t2.SID 
    AND
    t1.ADate = t2.ADate
```